# Criptografia em Java com AES, como funciona?

Tags: java, android, criptografia

Já encontrei vários exemplos pelo Google, mas nenhum que explique direito como funciona uma criptografia em java com AES... Como funciona?

Em um exemplo da net, o cara cita que tem que usar uma chave, mas não explica o porque e nem para que serve;

ex:

```
public static final byte[] CHAVE = {85, 10, 0, -25, 68, 88, 46, 37, 107, 48, 10, -1, -37, -90, 70, -36};
```

Para que serve a chave? 
Pode ser qualquer valor?
O que essa AES tem de diferente das outras?
Funciona no Android?

**Edit:**
Depois de uma conversa nos comentários, entendi que tenho que usar uma chave estática, pois a usarei num game, somente para guardar um valor usando shared pref. do Android. Este valor é o maior rank do player!

Mas ainda cabe minha pergunta, pode ser qualquer valor? Entendi nada desse exemplo (a chave que postei)...

Comment: O AES funciona da mesma forma independente de plataforma, sistema operacional ou qualquer tipo de tecnologia que se utilize, já que se trata de um conjunto de operações matemáticas. É um algoritmo. Você pode encontrar [todo o blá-blá-blá científico na wiki](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) (aviso: a menos que você tenha tesão por essas coisas, é muito *booooooooring*).

Comment: Outra coisa: a chave serve para garantir que somente alguém com a chave correta (a mesma da encriptação para algoritmos simétricos, ou a outra chave do par no caso de algoritmos assimétricos) possa decriptar a mensagem. Caso contrário não é criptografia, pois se não houver chave qualquer um pode decifrar suas mensagens. Se alguém quiser desenvolver essas ideias numa resposta mais completa, ganha meu +1.

Comment: vi que tem como gerar uma chave, tornando a aplicação mais segura, mas no meu caso, creio eu que isso é inviável, eu preciso gravar uma informação criptografada num arquivo gerado pelo shared pref do Android, creio então que a chave teria que ser estática! Mas como funciona esta chave? Pelo exemplo que citei... pode ser qualquer valor?

Comment: A chave é um **conjunto de bytes** que é usado para encriptar a informação que você precisa esconder - por esse motivo, geralmente se trabalha com *Arrays* de bytes (é assim em .NET e Java, pelo menos). O resultado de uma encriptação é um conjunto de bytes que não faz o menor sentido para nada nem ninguém até que seja decriptado. No caso do AES, esse conjunto só pode ser decriptado com a mesma chave que foi usada na encriptação. A sua segurança depende dessa chave ser secreta. Pense em informação encriptada como ouro dentro de um cofre, e a chave como a combinação que abre o cofre ;)

Comment: Vamos ver a coisa de outro ângulo: você encripta informação pra manter ela secreta. Se você deixar a chave junto do arquivo encriptado, você não está escondendo nada, ao menos não no aparelho Android onde a chave vai ficar. Talvez você queira fazer algo mais simples do que criptografia? Se você incluir seu objetivo final na pergunta, talvez alguém possa sugerir outros meios de alcançá-lo.

Comment: eu pensei muito e creio que a solução seja esta, pois é para um game que já fiz, mas ele tem uma pequena falha... O rank (somente o best) é gravado com shared pref. Uma pessoa com acesso root pode facilmente alterar este arquivo, aumentando seu rank, eu uso este arquivo somente para gravar o rank e retornar este dado ao iniciar a tela de gameover... No caso da criptografia eu geraria uma chave estática, mas ela não ficaria armazenada no arquivo, somente o valor do rank encriptado ficaria!

Comment: Também não adianta usar SQLite, daria no mesmo, eu somente armazeno um valor... O problema é alguém alterar este valor, eu sei que tem hackers que decompilam o APK e conseguem ler mesmo eu usando proguard, mas eu queria pelo menos impedir os noobs e leigos de alterar o rank

Comment: Você nunca vai impedir um hacker desocupado de mexer no seu APK. Mas como se trata de um jogo e não de uma aplicação bancária ou militar, acho tranquilo deixar a chave no código. Espero que alguém possa lhe dar uma resposta adequada e com exemplos aqui (eu mesmo sou um zero a esquerda com Java...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As chaves criptográficas são o que definem a saída do algoritmo de criptografia. Elas são definidas em bits. Como na maioria das linguagens de programação a menor unidade possível é o byte, elas são representadas por bytes. Um byte equivale a oito bits, então uma chave de 128 bits terá 16 bytes.

Você não deve escolher a chave, nem mesmo deve buscar uma chave na web. Você deve usar um gerador seguro de chaves criptográficas, que vai gerar um chave aleatória e vai garantir que chave tenha uma entropia alta.

Em Java, uma forma de gerar é essa:

```
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGen.init(256); // Tamanho da chave como exemplo.
SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
```

Sua outra questão, conforme levantada nos comentários, diz respeito à segurança de jogos em dispositivos móveis. Essa é uma questão complexa, que envolve diferentes fatores e depende da tecnologia utilizada. Leve em conta que é muito difícil criar um jogo completamente seguro. A maioria dos jogos mais populares nas lojas de aplicativos possui falhas de segurança.